# Spatial autocorrelation analysis (Global Moran`s I) suspicious z-score

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have a doubt concerning the Spatial autocorrelation analysis Global Moran's I, in ArcGIS 10.2. I did the analysis with 3.372 features of a defined study area, and it showed that the features are clustered. But I am not convinced with the results, because they are too high: the p-value is 0, and the z-score, 40,12. Is this possible? The result seems suspicious.

Comment: A formal test of this sort has value only when there are very few data or when the clustering is so subtle it is difficult to identify visually. When the clusters are clearly apparent, you will always get enormous z-scores and p-values that are essentially zero. The [local Moran's I](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p00000012000000)--which can be mapped--provides more, and more interesting, information. It will show you which locations are contributing most to that largish z-score.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any limit (mathematically speaking) to the z-score. I've got results up to 100-200 in some occasions. Just google search images of the morans zscore results and you will see a lot of cases with scores greater than 40.